# Space is being created when the input box get its focus on signin field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I am working on sign-in page and am using JQuery finally, i hope everything is working fine except on small issue. I mean the space is being created when the **password** field get its focus **only** on **IE 8** and later.

Problem is: space is being created when the **password** field get its focus on sign-in field on **IE8 only** and **not other browsers**.

My aim is: it **should not** create space when when the **password** field get its focus on sign-in field on **IE8**.

See the below pictures

Before, mouse get its focus[IE8].

[image]

After, mouse get its focus[IE8].

[image]

my html code as follows

```
<input name="ctl00$logInBox$UserName" type="text" maxlength="256" id="ctl00_logInBox_UserName" class="userName" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Username" />
<input name="ctl00$logInBox$Password_TXT" type="text" maxlength="256" id="ctl00_logInBox_Password_TXT" class="password" autocomplete="off" value="Password" style="display:none" />
<input name="ctl00$logInBox$Password" type="password" maxlength="256" id="ctl00_logInBox_Password" class="password" autocomplete="off" value="" />
```

and JQuery for this is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#ctl00_logInBox_Password').hide();

                $('#ctl00_logInBox_Password_TXT').show();

                $('#ctl00_logInBox_Password_TXT').focus(function () {
                    $(this).hide();
                    $('#ctl00_logInBox_Password').show().focus();
                });

                $('#ctl00_logInBox_Password').blur(function () {
                    if ($(this).val() == "") {
                        $(this).hide();
                        $('#ctl00_logInBox_Password_TXT').show();
                    }

                });

            });
</script>
```

CSS Portion is

```
.login .field input.userName, .login .field input.password {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #e9e9e9;
    border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
    width: 18.3em !important; /*width value changed by sakthivel*/
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1.4 !important;
    font-size: 15px !important;
    width: 309px !important;
    padding: 5px 8px 6px !important;
    color: #808080;
}
```

Comment: what does the css for the input look like?

Comment: I just added the CSS stuffs on the answer

Comment: try putting the tags on the same physical line. browsers interpret whitespace, including line breaks, differently

Comment: I remember reading that there can be issues with inline block on IE8 there was a fix  { *display:inline; } but not sure that would be it if it's only when the field has focus. Also why are you declaring two width's in the css?

Comment: @Sakthivel Please Select a answer so that others can have a point of call of where to start when looking at the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be a different style on the :focus otherwise this wouldn't happen, go into google chrome open dev tools inspect the div and click the little box on the right that says :foc and that will set the item to focused without being focused then check all the css on the right and it might tell you the reason why.

Also make a fiddle so that we can test it ourselves always helpful